# Oracle table update in same transaction with smaller chunk

Tags: java, oracle, performance, sql-update

We are trying to update a table in Oracle DB, which has more than 300 000 rows. So my requirement is to update table in smaller chunks, in same transaction. How to do it?

Comment: Could you show us the code ?

Comment: 3 lakh = 300.000, right? What's wrong with a single UPDATE?

Comment: Given that you want a single transaction, what benefit do you think you'll gain from smaller chunks?

Comment: so big update is opening transaction for long time,which is creating problem in database pipeline.

Comment: There is a DB concept known as a "cursor". Remember the ResultSet will occupy DB memory until you close the cursor, and the DB is a shared resource ...

Comment: There is no need to make things slower by updating in chunks. Especially not with such a small table.

Comment: So Transaction is opened for more tna 10 minute,which is cloging database pipeline

Comment: Define 'pipline'.  Define 'clogging'.  Before you can tune the app, you have to know exactly where the time is going.  To get any help from someone else, you need to show the code.

Comment: Consider not doing an update, but rather creating a new table with updated data then swapping that back in for the original table with "rename".